# Integrating multivariable function with respect to x while y depends on x!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, partial-derivative

When we want to solve an Exact Differential Equation of the form $P(x, y)dx + Q(x, y)dy = 0$ we have a solution of the form:
$$f(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x}{P(x, y)dx} + \int_{y_0}^{y}{Q(x_o, y)dy} = c$$

My question is the following:

In the first part I must perform an integration with regard to x. As the book I am reading says, I must calculate this integral keeping y constant. But we know that $y$ is a function of $x$ .($y = y(x)$). Is it mathematically correct to do that, despite the fact that during integration $x$ moves in the interval $(x_0, x)$?

Second question similar to the previous one:

The definition of the exact ODE says that for it to be exact the following must happen for a function $f(x, y)$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) = P(x, y) \space and \space \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = Q(x, y)$$
We know once again that y is a function of x. So is it correct for the second partial derivative to differentiate with regard to $y$ and keep $x$ constant?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not implied that $y$ is a function of $x$. This whole exercise is about real functions in two variables, regardless of its connection to differential equations.

You should also make a distinction between independent, free variables and integration variables
$$
f(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x}{P(\tilde x, y)d\tilde x} + \int_{y_0}^{y}{Q(x_0, \tilde y)d\tilde y} = c
$$
from where it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) = P(x,y)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(\tilde x, y)d\tilde x + Q(x_0,y)
$$
If the integrability condition $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ is satisfied, the second transforms to
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(\tilde x, y)d\tilde x + Q(x_0,y)=Q(x,y).
$$
Now you can try to prove that the integrability condition is not only sufficient, but also necessary.

Comment: It's a differential equation. So y MUST be a function of x (or x a function of y). What I mean is that for a specific $x_0$, y takes a specific value; $y(x_0)$ (by definition of a function). Hence $P(x, y) = P(x, y(x)) => P = P(x)$

Comment: $Pdx+Qdy=0$ is an exact differential equation which defines a direction field in the plane. The common first solution step is finding a first integral $f$. Up to that point everything is 2-dimensional calculus, no differential equation involved. Solutions of the exact differential equations are then the level curves of $f$, in the implicit solution of $f(x,y(x))=C$ you get $y(x)$ as function of $x$.

Comment: Ignoring that $y$ and $x$ have a dependance and treating them as two independent variables which can take values idnependently the one from the other isn't a little bit counter-intuitive? Furthermore, if I write the exact ODE as $P+Qy' = 0$, am I allowed to treat $y$ and $x$ as two independent variables?

Comment: That is the associated ODE, where of course $y$ is a function of $x$. Sometimes it is more obvious to solve, other times it might be $Px'(y)+Q=0$. Another associated ODE system is $\dot x(t)=-Q(x(t),y(t))$, $\dot y(t)=P(x(t),y(t))$. These are 4 related, but different problems with different sets of free and dependent variables.

Comment: So to summarize. Even if $y$ in the end is dependent to $x$, we treat them as two independent variables. We let $y$ and $x$ take any value in the region $R$ and integrate once with regard to $x$ and the other with regard to $y$. In the end, we have an 1-parameter family of solutions which describes the relation between $y$ and $x$. But that last one implies that there is no region $R$ (in which we integrated) but there is a two dimensional curve. Doesn't that mean that the integration we performed is false?